# Disk Clean up does not delete

Tags: windows, windows-10

I'm currently running a bit low on disk space so I decided to perform my monthly Disk clean up on Windows 10, however it seems that there is an issue because the option for Windows Update Cleanup (which shows nearly 7 GB that could be cleaned) does not delete anything at all.

[image: Disk Cleanup - Clean up system files]

I've checked if there are any updates pending that might block this operation from working correctly, however everything seems up to date. Is there anything I could do in order to eventually locate these items manually or have the Disk Cleanup fixed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you reboot after performing the cleanup? Some content in Disk Cleanup is only actually deleted when fully shutting down or rebooting.

Answer (score 2):

You can narrow down to the Windows Update cache folder to free up disk space:

1. To start, we need to stop the **Windows update service** before we can clear the update cache. To do that, search for “**Services**” in the Start menu and open it. If you are using your system as a standard user, then open it as an administrator using the right-click menu.
2. Once the Services window has been opened, find the service “**Windows Update**,” right-click on it and then select the option “**Stop**.” This action stops the Windows update service.
3. After stopping the service, press “**Win + R**,” enter the below path and press the Enter button. This is the folder where Windows stores all the files related to Windows updates **%WinDir%\SoftwareDistribution**
4. Once you are in this folder, open the “**Download**” folder, select all the files in it and just press the Delete key on your keyboard to delete all the files. You might be prompted for administrator permissions; simply click on the “Continue” button to complete the procedure.
5. Open the Services window again and start the **Windows Update service** again by right-clicking on it and then select the option “**Start**.”

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Karen Hu. This worked to a certain extent but not entirely. I went through your mentioned steps but the SoftwareDistribution folder only contained 2.2 GB of files. After stopping the service, deleting the files and re-starting the Windows Update Service I also rebooted my system  in order to re-check the Disk Cleanup Utility which however, seems to be unchanged (as per my screenshot above) as it still shows 6.97 GB that could be cleaned from "Windows Update Cleanup" .. mhmhm..

Comment: What's build of your Windows 10? Have you exit the disk cleanup and then restart the computer to re-launch the disk cleanup to check the result?

Comment: Hi Karen Hu. Windows 10 Pro version 1703 (OS Build 15063.674) and yes, sure, restarted the computer several times but same situation

Comment: That's odd and my Windows 10 1703 has no this issue. Please check and install all available Windows Updates to see if it can solve this issue. If no, i suggest you upgrade it to Windows 10 1709 or use Windows 10 1703 ISO to do repair installation.